# What is the logical difference between <nav> and class="nav" attr in bootstrap4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to understand the semantics of how bootstrap tags or classes work.
Here, "nav" is class attribute.

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But below, in case of  tag - it's actually a tag, not class attribute.

```
<nav class="nav">
  <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
</nav>
```

What's the difference, does bootstrap introduce BOTH classes and its own custom html tags to standard html5 tags?

So I can make my own tags or only use tags from bootstrap?

Comment: There are no custom tags here. [`<nav>` is standard HTML.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element)

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't make a distinction between `<nav class="nav">` or `"<div class="nav">`. `<nav>` was added in HTML5 for semantic purposes, but Bootstrap doesn't treat it differently since it only relies on the `.nav` class selector.